# How to get facebook friendslist with profile picture in swift ios?

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, ios8.3

i am new to swift language.how to get friendslist from facebook.i am using facebook graph api.I am getting profile picture,email,profile name.But,problem is only for friendslist.anyone please help me..

Comment: you can't get facebook friendlist...you get only facebook friends who install your app\\

Comment: facebook  2.0 deprecate this feature...if you want to add invite feature then https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites

Answer (score 0):

You  can't get the user's friends list Unless user's friends gives permission(user_friends) to your app. You can get only Friends count.